# LSF bsub: job always in PENDING state, not going to RUN state

Tags: unix

I stuck on a small problem.
I'm launching many bsub commands at the same time each one on a specified host:

```
bsub -sp 20 -W 0:5 -m $myhostname -q "myQueue" -J "mkdir_script" -o $log_file "script_to_launch param1 param2 param3"
```

all this inside a for, for each hostName.

The problem is that everything is OK for all hosts except one (always the same one). The job is always in PENDING state, and is not moving to RUN state.
The script to execute is a script that will check for a folder and creating it if is not there (so a very small task to do).
Is there a way to see what happens on that host  and why my job is not going to RUN state ?

PS: I just found the `bjobs -p` command and I have the following message:

```
 Not specified in job submission: 81 hosts;
 Closed by LSF administrator: 3 hosts;
```

What does this message mean?

Answer (score 2):

The `-m` option limits you to a particular host, which excludes 81 hosts. The other three have been closed by your system administrator. You would have to contact them to find out why.